# If there exists a $P \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ that $PAP^{-1}=B$ then we can find a $Q \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ that $QAQ^{-1}=B$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Assume that $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and there is an invertible matrix $P \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ that $PAP^{-1}=B$.
>   Prove that there is an invertible matrix $Q\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ that $QAQ^{-1}=B$

(By the symbol $M_n(F)$, we mean all $n\times n $ matrices over the field $F$.)

**Please note the change in field from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$**

Comment: I presume you are missing something, just take $Q=P$. You need to fix the question, it is truly trivial as is.

Comment: So, it is needed to prove that the imaginary part of each element of $P$ is $0$. How to prove it? @copper.hat

Comment: My apologies, I missed the change of field.

Comment: Are you the same person as the user Petar? He asked the same question a moment ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722091/real-and-complex-invertible-matrices

Comment: This *can* be done using real Jordan forms. I wonder if there's a solution that avoids that result.

Comment: @user251257 No  I'm not that one! just a funny coincidence!

Comment: This is not so easy to prove in my opinion. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57242/similar-matrices-and-field-extensions?lq=1 for a more genral question.

Comment: We might also note that $Q\mapsto QA - BQ$ is a linear map, and that our $Q$s lie in the kernel of this map.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom there's an elementary proof in the question linked by Phoemuex

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think my solution is correct.
Generalized statement: $L/K$ - fields extension, $A,B\in M_{n}(K)$, $A\sim B$ over $L$. We need to prove, that $A\sim B$ over K. $$A\sim B \;\text over \;L \:\Longleftrightarrow\:\left(A-\lambda E\right)\approx\left(B-\lambda E\right)   (\approx\text - matrix\; equivalence)\; \text over\; L[\lambda]$$
$$\left(A-\lambda E\right)\approx diag(A-\lambda E)\;\; \text and \;\left(B-\lambda E\right)\approx diag(B-\lambda E)$$ over $K[\lambda]$,  $$diag(A-\lambda E)\approx diag(B-\lambda E)$$ over $L[\lambda]$ and $$diag(A-\lambda E)\sim diag(B-\lambda E)$$ over $K$ (permutation of diagonal elements), that means $$diag(A-\lambda E)\approx diag(B-\lambda E)$$ over $K[\lambda]$, that means $$\left(A-\lambda E\right)\approx\left(B-\lambda E\right)$$ over $K[\lambda]$ and  $A\sim B$ over $K$.