# $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ are similar over $\mathbb{R}$ if they are similar over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I want to prove the following statement:

> Assume that $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and there is an invertible matrix $P \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ that $PAP^{-1}=B$.
>   Prove that there is an invertible matrix $Q\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ that $QAQ^{-1}=B$

I know that there are some similar questions asked here and I've read all of them. But the point is that I don't want to use determinant approach. All the proofs that one can find here or on the internet are similar to the one you can find in the following link: [Similarity of real matrices over $\mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129628/similarity-of-real-matrices-over-mathbbc)

all of them use this reality that because $P=C+Di$ for some $C,D \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $det(C+Di) \neq 0$ so there exists a $t\in \mathbb{R}$ that $det(C+Dt)\neq0$ and so on.

I don't want to use this approach. Instead of using determinant, I want to use this theorem that a matrix $M$ is invertible if and only if the only answer for the system $MX=0$ is $X=0$.

Now, because the hypothesis says that $P$ is invertible we can say that the only answer for the system $PX=0$ or equivalently $(C+Di)X=0$ is $X=0$. We have:

$$(C+Di)X=0 \Rightarrow CX=0 , DX=0$$
Now, if we can prove that the only answer for the system $CX=0$ or $DX=0$ is $X=0$ then it means that $C$ or $D$ are invertible. Then we can write

$$PAP^{-1}=B \Rightarrow PA=BP$$
$$P=C+Di \Rightarrow CA+DAi=BC+BDi$$
$$CA=BC , DA=BD$$
Then we can conduce that $B=CAC^{-1}$ or $B=DAD^{-1}$ and the problem is solved. But $C$ and $D$ are not necessarily invertible. How can we construct a new real matrix, say $Q$ that $QAQ^-{1}=B$ by using the theorem that I've mentioned above(or some similar theorems) and **not using determinant approach**?

Comment: I already answered on this question
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722126/if-there-exists-a-p-in-m-n-mathbbc-that-pap-1-b-then-we-can-find-a/1722218#1722218

Comment: Yes, but your approach is similar to the determinant approach which I don't want to use. @B.Igor

Comment: The thread http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57242/similar-matrices-and-field-extensions?lq=1 already contains some answers that does not rely on the knowledge of determinant. E.g. Marc van Leeuwen has given a clean and general [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/602589/1551) using rational canonical form.

Comment: Note that $A,B$ may well be similar and thus have equal *spectra* (eigenvalues, up to multiplicities), but the shared eigenvalues may nonetheless include conjugate pairs of complex values.  Moreover the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue may exceed its geometric multiplicity (although $A,B$ will agree as to both by virtue of similarity over $\mathbb{C}$). The rational canonical form is one concise way of addressing these subtleties.